# use current date as a search parameter through vb.net in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to query my database based on the current user and the current date. I currently am getting no results from my query and I think the problem is with my formatting of the current date in vb.net. The query as is

```
query = "SELECT movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username='" & currentUser & "' AND start_date<='" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND return_date>='" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"
```

I know the rest of the query works (except calling the currentUser) as I have tested it on the mySql server. I have called currentUser before, which is saved through a variable in a module, without any hassle so I feel the problem has to be with my dates.
I don't know how to format the current date so mySql will receive it properly?
I have also tried the code

```
query = "SELECT movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username='" & currentUser & "' AND start_date<='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND return_date>='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"
```

with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Yes, but the problem shoul be fixed using a parameterzied query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the usual bad practice to use string concatenation when building sql command.
And the remedy is always the same. A parameterized query.

```
 query = "SELECT movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=" & _
         "(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username=@name"  &_
         " AND start_date<=@date AND return_date>=@date"
 Using cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentUser
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
       .... now read your data ....
    End Using
End Using
```

With string concatenation you are vulnerable to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and when forcing the conversion of decimals or date to a string you are an easy victim of wrong conversions. Parameters avoid all of that

EDIT: With an MySqlDataAdapter

```
 query = "SELECT movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=" & _
         "(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username=@name"  &_
         " AND start_date<=@date AND return_date>=@date"
 Using cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentUser
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    Using adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       Dim dt = new DataTable()
       adapter.Fill(dt)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I want to show the data through a data frame so i was using a MySqlDataAdapter rather than a reader, how would I change the code to do this?

Comment: In that case, you could use the MySqlDataAdapter constructor that takes an MySqlCommand and pass the command prepared above instead of creating/using  an MySqlDataReader